# Column not getting updated in production but works fine in Test

Tags: magento-1.7, database

I have a magento site and a MYSQL table where sellerprofile is saved. I manually added a column to this table

```
ALTER TABLE `XYZ` ADD COLUMN `ABC` AFTER `CDE`
```

Now when I am trying to update a value to this column using my magento code then it is not saving this value. If I try to do a SQL update then it works just fine.

The Magento update

```
$collection->save()
```

does not return any error either. All other columns get updated except this particular column. I did a Mage::log on this and till the save point, the variable does carry the correct value. It just does not show up in the database.

Strangely this works perfectly in my TEST env which is not very different from PROD.

What am I missing here?

Comment: i think reindex problem try to reindex. it not reflect frontend right?

Comment: its not there in the database itself ... I checked using phpmyadmin. Since its not there in db, the frontend also does not have it. I had re-indexed and tried but did not work. Can try again and will post back.

Comment: That column is created or not ?

Comment: yes the column is created and i can see it in phpmyadmin

Comment: Did you flush the cache ? Magento maintains table definitions in cache even if it is not enabled via admin.

Comment: Thank you both ... Thank you ..... Flushing the cache worked. I actually was flushing the magento cache... this time i flushed storage cache as well and it worked. Please do answer this in the right spot so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you flush the cache ? Magento maintains table definitions in cache even if it is not enabled via admin.